# Как остановить функцию при зажатой кнопке мышки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
let num = 0;
const max = $('.technology-timeline-tab').length;
function autoplay() {
    $('.technology-timeline-tab').each(function (id) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line radix
            num = parseInt(id) + 1;
        }
    });
    if (num >= max) {
        num = 0; // Или обнуляем или останавливаем: return false;
    }
    $('.technology-timeline-tab').removeClass('active');
    $('.technology-timeline-tab').eq(num).trigger('click');
    setTimeout(autoplay, 5000);
}

$('.technology-timeline-content__section').mousedown(function () {
    $(this).addClass('mousedown');
    if ($('.technology-timeline-content__section').hasClass('mousedown')) {
        console.log('стоять');
        return;------------ не работает. пишет ESLint: Unnecessary return statement.(no-useless-return)
    }
});

$(window).mouseup(function () {
    if ($('.technology-timeline-content__section').hasClass('mousedown')) {
        $('.technology-timeline-content__section').removeClass('mousedown');
        autoplay();
        console.log('пошла');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сохранять id таймера и отменять его при нажатии

```
let num = 0;
const max = $('.technology-timeline-tab').length;
let autoplayTimer; // переменная для id
function autoplay() {
    $('.technology-timeline-tab').each(function (id) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line radix
            num = parseInt(id) + 1;
        }
    });
    if (num >= max) {
        num = 0; // Или обнуляем или останавливаем: return false;
    }
    $('.technology-timeline-tab').removeClass('active');
    $('.technology-timeline-tab').eq(num).trigger('click');
    autoplayTimer = setTimeout(autoplay, 5000); // сохранили
}

$('.technology-timeline-content__section').mousedown(function () {
    $(this).addClass('mousedown');
    console.log('стоять');
    clearTimeout(autoplayTimer); // остановили
});

$(window).mouseup(function () {
    if ($('.technology-timeline-content__section').hasClass('mousedown')) {
        $('.technology-timeline-content__section').removeClass('mousedown');
        autoplay();
        console.log('пошла');
    }
});
```

[setTimeout | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)
[clearTimeout | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)

На счёт `ESLint: Unnecessary return statement.(no-useless-return)`: у вас подключён линтер, который следит за тем, что бы в коде не было лишнего мусора. В данном случае, он жалуется на то, что вы поставили `return`, который не имеет смысла, т.к. находится в конце функции и не возвращает значения.

Comment: Спасибо! работает )